# How to append tokens to a string variable in C?

Tags: c, string, append, token

So I have the following code:

```
//Get the line

fgets(line, MAX, stdin);

//Remove trailing new line character

line[strcspn(line, "\r\n")] = 0;

//Count number of tokens

int tokenCounter = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < strlen(line); i++){
    if (line[i] == ' '){
        tokenCounter++;
    }
}if (tokenCounter >= 3){
    command = strtok(line, " ");
    id = strtok(NULL, " ");
    name = strtok(NULL, " ");
    if (tokenCounter > 3){
        for (char *p = strtok(NULL," "); p != NULL; p = strtok(NULL, " ")){
            strcat(name, p);
        }
    }
    printf("Command: %s -- ID: %s -- Name: %s\n", command, id, name);
}
```

What the code is supposed to do is it is supposed to save the first word in the line in the "command" variable, the second word in the line in the "id" variable and the rest of the words in a single variable called "name". But currently its not working properly. It works as described below:

```
Input  >  word1 word2 word3
Output >  Command: word1 -- ID: word2 -- Name: word3

Input  >  word1 word2 word3 word4
Output >  Illegal Instruction: 4
```

The correct outputs are supposed to be as follows :

```
Input  >  word1 word2 word3
Output >  Command: word1 -- ID: word2 -- Name: word3

Input  >  word1 word2 word3 word4
Output >  Command: word1 -- ID: word2 -- Name: word3 word 4
```

Am I doing something wrong in the loop? if yes, what could be changed?

Comment: what's up with strtok(NULL, "  ") ? passing NULL when the function expects an actual variable will always result in a program crashing

Comment: I read it somewhere and tried it and it works when I only have 3 tokens but not when 4. Any idea on how to solve the problem? You do understand the problem right?

Comment: yes I do, try looking at this code snippet, it accomplishes what you need with a while loop https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strtok.htm

Comment: @WalidJabari the snippet is storing the tokens in the same variable yet I need to store them in different variables.

Comment: You don't show your declarations, so it hard to say what is wrong, but there is no 'string' type in C so you can't have a "string variable".  Variables need to be char arrays to hold strings, and need to be large enough to hold them without overflow.

Comment: @ChrisDodd I have updated the question. Please take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's lots that could be wrong with your incomplete code, but one clear problem is the loop:

```
for (int i = 3; i <= tokenCounter; i++){
    name = strtok(NULL, " ");
    if (tokenCounter > 3)
        strcat(name, strtok(NULL, " "));
}
```

The first time through the loop, this will assign `name` to be pointer to the scanning buffer, which will not work if `name` is `char name[MAX];` (which it needs to be for any of your code to have any hope of working), so you should be seeing a compile error.  Then, `strtok` returns `NULL` when it gets to the end of the input, which will likely cause an immediate crash when you pass it to `strcat`.  What you need is something more like

```
    name = strcpy(strtok(NULL, " "));
    while (char *tmp = strtok(NULL, " ")) {
        strcat(name, " ");
        strcat(name, tmp);;
    }
```

Not that this is all that good, as it does not check for buffer overflows, and is just splitting an reassembling tokens, so why bother?  Just use `strtok(NULL, "\n");` to get the whole rest of the line as a single "token".

---

If you've erroneously declared `char *name;`, that probably explains your crash.  When you do

```
name = strtok(NULL, " ");
if (tokenCounter > 3){
    for (char *p = strtok(NULL," "); p != NULL; p = strtok(NULL, " ")){
        strcat(name, p);
```

The first line makes `name` point at the strtok buffer, and then in the loop you attempt to append part of the buffer to itself, which causes undefined behavior.

Comment: Where would you declare temp?

Comment: I used ```name = strtok(NULL, "\n");``` and it worked like a charm! Thanks!